# Part of transactionProducts info not being recorded in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Hey Guys I have data layer hard coded on a confirmation page and all tags are configured in GTM. I have setup a GA transaction tag and set the trigger as custom event = the event being setup in data layer.

However, on GA ecomm data, only the price is being recorded while SKU and product name / category is not showing on GA.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the e-commerce code being pushed to the dataLayer is not according to the required format of GTM
See here for format details :
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en

Assuming that the above is not the issue, there could be some special character being used in your e-commerce code which is causing the code to break

Hope this helps.